# Android video player can't open file on some devices

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I'm seeing an issue with playing video file from Acer a500 running on android 4.0.3.

My application is saving mp4 file to internal storage under /data/data/com.myapp.app/videos/ then at some point it has to play the file and once I do:

```
   ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("videos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File savedFile = new File(directory, videoFileName);

        if (savedFile.exists()) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(savedFile.toURI()));
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

It results with dialog on the screen that says "Sorry, this video cannot be played".

The log files are showing the following:

```
06-10 17:18:37.666      85-1331/? D/AwesomePlayer﹕ Failed to open file, all profile flags have to set through setprop method.
06-10 17:18:37.666      85-1331/? I/AwesomePlayer﹕ setDataSource_l('/data/data/com.myapp.app/videos/short.mp4')
06-10 17:18:37.676    1394-1457/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
06-10 17:18:37.726    1394-1394/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

When I save my videoFile it is setting `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` not sure if that matters.

I don't see any issues on most of devices playing video, however this one it is causing an error.

Any ideas on what could be missing?
Also if I choose to play video from web-streaming, it works fine.

Comment: What is the format/codec of your video ?

Comment: it's mpeg4
What i don't understand is that if i stream the same video from web server, it works. Also it works on many other devices i testing on.

Comment: Did you try with different media ? Do you observe the problem with this media only ?

Comment: so you are saying that maybe i just need to install some additional codecs on that device? I have about 10 files, all mp4, none being played on that acer. I also have 10 other devices that i'm testing on and i don't see that issue anywhere else

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to add additional capabilities to the `MediaPlayer` backends without recompiling the whole firmware.